# How to do validate login credentials in Framework 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm building an app using phone gap (to make the app cross platform) and need to validate user credentials entered into a login page. I can do this in php (which is what I'm using to get the data from the database) but I don't think phone gap can run PHP natively. Currently I am able to use ajax get query results returned in a PHP file, but in order to do input validation, I would need to first send the user input to the PHP file, check the passed input with the results of the database query and then send that back to the html file in a JSON file to the ajax call. This seems pretty convoluted so I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inbuilt.. you must do validation in server side php, its not possible in withing app without php

just ajax to validate these on server then using `localStorage` save session details and reuse them whenever need.

```
Framework7.$.ajax();
```

or you can automate form ajax using http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/form-ajax-submit.html